# Getting a DNS query in C on port 53. What is the address to bind to?

Tags: c, sockets, proxy, dns

I am building a simple DNS proxy server in C which must receive a request from a DNS client (which will be using UDP) on port 53, forward the query to a different server, get a response from the server and sent it back to the client.

I've tried to implement pseudo-code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4220469/6512709), but I've stuck with receiving query.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define ERROR -1

void    error_die(char *err_msg)
{
    perror(err_msg);
    exit(-1);
}

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == ERROR)
        error_die("socket");

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(53);
    inet_aton("192.168.0.1", &(servaddr.sin_addr));

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof servaddr) == ERROR)
        error_die("bind");
    return (0);
}
```

The "192.168.0.1" is the address of the DNS server found in /etc/resolv.conf. After running that I got *"bind: Can't assign requested address"*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `bind` with your address, not with the remote address. It is possible to use INADDR_ANY

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

If you need to receave packets, use `recvfrom`. You can also use `select` to check if there is any packet available before calling `recvfrom`.